# Ubuntu 15.10 constant Ethernet network freezes/not responding

Tags: networking, ethernet, 15.10

Lately I've been encountering these issues where my Ethernet connection suddenly stops working. It happens at random times and I can't find anything in the log files.

The adapter is Yukon Optima 88E8059 and it's connected to a 1 Gbit/s router. I'm sure the router is not a problem because I have tested it with other devices/same device on windows.
Even pinging from terminal doesn't show any errors, it just skips the packets like nothing happened.

Gnome and ifconfig show as if it it's connected at all the time.

Ping: First 2 images

Tail of /var/log/syslog from the relevant time: 3rd image

ifconfig: 4th image

Images: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggEVH.jpg)

EDIT: It has gotten worse, now I have over 75% package loss and the internet is unusable. Also the dig command never works but ping sometimes does. I had to revert to Windows temporarily.

Comment: Please include textual information as text and not as images in your question. It's much more accessible and searchable that way.

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. It works just as well for wired network connections. The best options would be to run the diagnostics both with a working and a non-working connection and post both results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem recently.
My device was conflicting (had the same IP address) as another device on the same network.

Comment: That is a (more detailed) problem description, not a solution. I recommend adding this information to the question and to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to solve this problem. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)